# Smarty foreach iteration new column every nth time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, foreach, iteration, smarty

I know that question was answered but in a little different way.

I want a new bootstrap column every 6th time of a loop so it looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#">LINK1</a>
        <a href="#">LINK2</a>
        <a href="#">LINK3</a>
        <a href="#">LINK4</a>
        <a href="#">LINK5</a>
        <a href="#">LINK6</a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#">LINK7</a>
        <a href="#">LINK8</a>
        <a href="#">LINK9</a>
        <a href="#">LINK10</a>
        <a href="#">LINK11</a>
        <a href="#">LINK12</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
<div class="row">
    {foreach name='sub_categories' from=$sub_categories item='sub'}
        {if $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.first or $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.iteration is div by 6}
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        {/if}
           <a href="#">LINK</a>
        {if $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.iteration-1 is div by 6}
        </div>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

But that doesn't work, because:

```
$smarty.foreach.sub_categories.iteration is div by 6
```

is true when the 6th iteration starts so smarty creates a new column after 5 iterations. Also the `<div>` is not closed the 6th time but the 5th time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is using index instead of iteration, because index starts at 0

```
<div class="row">
    {foreach name='sub_categories' from=$sub_categories item='sub'}
        {if $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.first or $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.index is div by 6}
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        {/if}
           <a href="#">LINK</a>
        {if $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.last || $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.iteration is div by 6}
        </div>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

also you may probably want to check sub_categories.last for the closing div, just in case the number of items is not a multiple of 6, i.e. 9

Comment: Thanks. When i try {if $smarty.foreach.sub_categories.index is div by 6} it's the true for the very first iteration. Why is "is div by 6" true on the first iteration?

Comment: Well, the first index is 0 and 0 is divisible by any number; actually you could remove the sub_categories.first condition and it still would work. That's why you have to use index in the first condition and iteration in the second

Comment: Oh! I've missed that little detail that you changed index in iteration. Thank you! It works now. :)